# Process by rows adding values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to transpose and sum with the following criteria: I have to create a row for each LOGIN and DATE and a column with the ACT values and the sum of their respective MAP values. In the middle separated by `:` I have to create the sum of all the MAP values, as follows:

```
LOGIN   DATE    ACT MAP
1   11/02/2008  149 3
1   11/02/2008  18  1
1   11/02/2008  18  1
1   11/02/2008  18  5
1   13/02/2008  145 2
1   13/02/2008  43  3
2   13/02/2008  19  0
2   13/02/2008  18  1
2   14/02/2008  18  1
2   14/02/2008  18  1
3   14/02/2008  39  1
3   15/02/2008  149 0
3   15/02/2008  43  0
3   15/02/2008  19  1
3   15/02/2008  19  1
```

`1 11/02/2008 149 18 : 10: 3 7` This is the first row that I should create because 149 and 18 are the ACT values for this LOGIN and DATE, 3 = MAP value for ACT 149 and 7 is the sum of the MAP values for ACT 18, 7=1+1+5, in the middle the 10 value = 3+7

```
1 13/02/2008 145 43 : 5: 2 3 
2 13/02/2008 19 18 : 1: 1 0
2 14/02/2008 18 : 2 : 2
3 14/02/2008 39 : 1 : 1
3 15/02/2008 149 43 19 : 2 : 0 0 2
```

I grouped and added to obtain this but need to process by rows

```
LOGIN   MAP
1           15
11/02/2008  10
13/02/2008  5
2           3
13/02/2008  1
14/02/2008  2
3           3
14/02/2008  1
15/02/2008  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I transformed the input file and now it looks like this, now I need to concatenate the values of the ACT column until I find a blank row.  For example I need to create `18 149 10 7 3` for the first group until the first blank. For the second blank I need to create `43 145 5 3 2`

```
LOGIN   ACT  Total
1       18     7
1      149     3
1              10
1       43     3
1       145    2
1              5
2       18     1
2       19     0
2              1
2       18     2
2              2
3       39     1
3              1
3       19     2
3       43     0
3       149    0
3              2
```